# Export / Download Table HTML-PHP to Excel file

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, export-to-excel

I have a table on HTML/PHP that extract data from mySQL. Please see in this [link](https://anakpanti.com/ab-cargo/controllers_searchshipment/). For example, please search this shipment code to get the result inside the table: **42-7278954**.

After that, I want to export the result to excel (you also can see the button there).

Below is my table code in view (I've deleted some columns to shorten the code):

```
$body = "";

$display =  "<table class='table_searchshipment' id='table_searchshipment' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' border='0'>";

            echo $display;
            $body .= $display;

            $display  = "<thead>
                        <tr>
                          <th>CN No.</th>
                          <th>Doc No.</th>
                        </tr>
                      </thead>";
            echo $display;
            $body .= $display;  

            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                $CN_no= $row['CN_no'];
                $doc_no= $row['doc_no'];

                $display  = "<tr>
                        <td>".$CN_no."</td>
                        <td>".$doc_no."</td>
                      </tr>";
               echo $display;
               $body .= $display;
            }

            $display  = "</table>";
            echo $display;
            $body .= $display;
            $body = htmlspecialchars($body);

            echo '<form action = "setheader" method = "post">
                    <input type = "hidden" name = "body" value = "<?php echo $body ; ?>">
                <input type = "submit" name = "submit" Value = "Export to excel">
            </form>'; 

            if(isset($_POST['submit'])){ 
                    $body = $_POST['body'];
                    setHeader("export.xls");

                    echo $body;
                }
```

And in the controller, I make function setheader:

```
public function setheader($excel_file_name)//this function used to set the header variable
{   
    header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");//A MIME attachment with the content type "application/octet-stream" is a binary file.
    //Typically, it will be an application or a document that must be opened in an application, such as a spreadsheet or word processor. 
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$excel_file_name");//with this extension of file name you tell what kind of file it is.
    header("Pragma: no-cache");//Prevent Caching
    header("Expires: 0");//Expires and 0 mean that the browser will not cache the page on your hard drive
   }
```

The download pop-up is appear, but it only download "setheader" file that contains of error notification. Please see it [here](https://anakpanti.com/setheader).

Comment: Try using $this->setHeader("export.xls");

Comment: I try to add it inside the setheader function, but I get *Internal Server Error*.

Comment: if(isset($_POST['submit'])){ 
                    
                    $this->setHeader("export.xls");
                }

Comment: oh, you mean in view. haha. I've replaced **setHeader("export.xls");** to become **$this->setHeader("export.xls");** but the result is still same.

Comment: public function setheader($excel_file_name="export.xls"){

Comment: well... it succeed to download "export.xls", but the file is empty. Is it means that my "post" method is not working?

Comment: I can see one issue here. This line ```<input type = "hidden" name = "body" value = "<?php echo $body ; ?>">``` should be ```<input type = "hidden" name = "body" value = "'.$body.'">```

Comment: @CUGreen thank you for figuring it out. Yeah... it's one of the issues here. I've changed the value, but the excel is still blank. :(

Comment: No probs. I think it is most likely ```htmlspecialchars``` then. Are you able to show what your db data is? There maybe some problematic characters in there.

Comment: Oh my God!!! Yes! *htmlspecialchars* is also the culprit here. Haha. Thank you very much. It's solved now. Thank you, Roshan and CUGreen. Why don't you guys submit the answer? So I can approve your answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly,

This line needs to change from:

```
echo '<form action = "setheader" method = "post">
        <input type = "hidden" name = "body" value = "<?php echo $body ; ?>">
    <input type = "submit" name = "submit" Value = "Export to excel">
</form>';
```

to:

```
echo '<form action = "setheader" method = "post">
        <input type = "hidden" name = "body" value = "'.$body.'">
    <input type = "submit" name = "submit" Value = "Export to excel">
</form>';
```

Secondly, `$body = htmlspecialchars($body);` is most likely returning an empty string.

From the [PHP Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php)

> If the input string contains an invalid code unit sequence within the
>   given encoding an empty string will be returned, unless either the
>   ENT_IGNORE or ENT_SUBSTITUTE flags are set.

Without knowing what data is coming from the database, it is hard to test that further.

But you could try:

`$body = htmlspecialchars($body, ENT_QUOTES | ENT_SUBSTITUTE, 'UTF-8');` to see if it solves that issue.