# Positioning of Table Cells in PDF messed up after converting it from PHP using fpdf

Tags: php, pdf, fpdf, pdf-conversion

I have a table in HTML-PHP (extract from mySQL). I want to convert it to pdf using fpdf. The convert process is success, but the problem is the position of every single cell is really mess up.

I've tried this code:

```
$pdf -> SetY(4);    // set the cursor at Y position 4
$pdf->Cell(20,50,$body);  // draw a cell at pos 4 that has a a width 20 and height 50
```

But the result is still become like this:
[image: view after export]
Even the header row is mess up.

For an example, you can try it [here](https://anakpanti.com/ab-cargo/controllers_searchshipment/) by searching 42-7278954 as Shipment Code and 965958038-X as Reference No. Then click button export to PDF.
[image: view before export]

You can see my code for view table (HTML-PHP) in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41356463/export-download-table-html-php-to-excel-file).

And here is my code so far:

```
public function setpdf()
   {
        require (__DIR__ . '/libraries/html_table.php');
    $body = $_POST['body'];
    $pdf=new PDF();
    $pdf->AddPage('L');
    $pdf->SetFont('Arial','',9);

    $pdf -> SetY(4);    // set the cursor at Y position 4
    $pdf->Cell(20,50,$body);  // draw a cell at pos 4 that has a a width 20 and height 50

    $pdf->WriteHTML($body);
    $pdf->Output();
   }
```

Link for viewing code in html_table.php is [here](https://anakpanti.com/share/html_table.txt)